# Custom ringtones don't work on Cyanogenmod 9

Tags: cyanogenmod, ringtone

I'm running Cyanogenmod 9 on my S3, and want to set an mp3 file as the ringtone. As [this wiki page](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/Custom_Sounds) suggests, I've created the directory '/sdcard/media/ringtones` and put the sound files in there.

Just to be sure, I put both an mp3 file and an ogg file (of different songs) there. They're world-readable. The ogg file does not show up in the "choose ringtone" dialogue. The mp3 file does show up. However, when I choose it, there's no preview sound, as there is with the other ringtones that came with CM9.

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Before you wipe your phone, consider using a free app like [Ringdroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ringdroid) to assign contacts with specific ringtones or even to just make a custom ringtone out of an mp3 track of choice.

Answer (score 1):

This was an issue which has been carried over from gingerbread. Although it has been long since it was fixed and merged into gingerbread too. It should work out of the box. Also could you mention as to whether you are using the latest CM9 build for your device. My friend's S3 with CM9 doesn't have this problem.
Why don't you try wiping your sdcard along with your system once for a clean install.